# why the length of this go slice is 4 and why the output has the space in slice?

Tags: go

I am new to golang and while running this code snippet I am getting the len as 4, trying to understand why so ?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type phone struct {
    model  string
    camera Camera
    ram    int
}

type Camera struct {
    lens      string
    aparature int
}

func main() {

    var m = make(map[string]phone)

    myphn1 := phone{model: "iphone", camera: Camera{"20", 4}, ram: 6}
    myphn2 := phone{model: "pixel", camera: Camera{"50", 2}, ram: 6}

    m["myphn1"] = myphn1
    m["myphn2"] = myphn2

    var k = make([]string, len(m))

    for key, _ := range m {
        k = append(k, key)
    }

    fmt.Println(k)
    fmt.Println(len(k))

}
```

I understand this adds size of 2 while creating, but while printing it gives somelike this , is the space in answer for 2 unallocated entries ?

```
[  myphn2 myphn1]
4
```

Comment: Yes, the spaces are the separators between the first two elements, both being empty strings.

Comment: For what it's worth, this same bug—confusing the initial length with the initial capacity—hits a lot of us on our first foray into Go.

Comment: thank you Peter and Torek :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This creates a slice of length 2 (`len(m)` is 2 here):

```
var k = make([]string, len(m))
```

This adds two elements to it, for a total of 4:

```
for key, _ := range m {
    k = append(k, key)
}
```

If you want to preallocate a slice, you need to provide a length of zero along with the desired capacity:

```
var k = make([]string, 0, len(m))
```

This is covered with examples in [the Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/13).

Answer (score 2):

You create a slice with length 2, and appended two more elements to it, so the length is 4.

what you probably want to do is to create a slice with capacity 2:

```
var k = make([]string,0,len(m))
```